# Timing in Golang with and without blank identifier

Tags: go, time

I am playing around with some elementary timing in Go and have a question. I want to time Golang in taking the square root of each element of an array but I get two somewhat different answers whether or not I keep the output. Here is the my first version:

```
package main

import ("fmt"
        "time" 
        "math"
        "math/rand"
)

// A random array of integers 
func randomArray(max int ,len int) []int {
    a := make([]int, len)
    for i := 0; i <= len-1; i++ {
        a[i] = rand.Intn(max)
    }
    return a
}

// Taking square root of each element in array
func sqrt_array(arr [] int) [] float64 {
    var len_arr = len(arr)
    a := make([]float64, len_arr)
    for i, v := range arr {
    a[i] = math.Sqrt(float64(v))
    }
    return a
}


func main() {

    arr := randomArray(100, 10e6)
    sqrt := make([]float64, len(arr))
    start := time.Now()
    sqrt = sqrt_array(arr)
    end := time.Now()

    fmt.Println("time taken: ", end.Sub(start), sqrt[0])
}
```

gives on average around 36ms:

```
time taken:  36.542019ms 9
```

Now when I replace the output "sqrt" with the blank identifier, I get something much slower. Specifically, I replace main() with

```
func main() {

    arr := randomArray(100, 10e6)
    // sqrt := make([]float64, len(arr))
    start := time.Now()
    _ = sqrt_array(arr)
    end := time.Now()

    fmt.Println("time taken: ", end.Sub(start))
}
```

and get on average something like 92ms

```
time taken:  92.121481ms
```

Would someone be able to explain what is happening? I feel that if I understood I might learn something about Go.

Incidentally I find that the same computation in Python was around 20ms if broadcasted and several hundred ms if in a loop.

Comment: If I had to make a guess, when you specify _, the allocated array gets destroyed before exiting the function because of compiler analysis, and that's the extra time.

Comment: How about this: allocate both arrays and pass them to the function before measuring, and see how long it takes? Or do the replacement in-place?

Answer (score 0):

@Not_a_Golfer that's an interesting idea thanks! I replaced sqrt_array with

```
func sqrt_array(arr [] int) [] float64 {
    var len_arr = len(arr)
    a := make([]float64, len_arr)
    s := time.Now()
    for i, v := range arr {
    a[i] = math.Sqrt(float64(v))
    }
    e := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("time taken: ", e.Sub(s))
    return a
}
```

and found that the first main() I used give:

time taken: 30.455811ms
time taken: 36.419998ms 9

while the second gives

time taken: 30.916246ms
time taken: 90.815387ms

I think this shows that the computation time of the two approaches is more or less the same (30ms). There may indeed be some time-cost (60ms or so) of deleting the array in the second option. Although that is weird since it should be just deleting a pointer